# Trouble in understanding Angular $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm having some troubles understanding Angular $location, and the difference and the HTML5 mode and the default one. (yes, I've already the guide about it).

Let's say I want to build a TODO list app.

I'd like to have one page 'myapp.com/user/#1' to display the user information. 'myapp.com/user' will perform a standard GET request and load the page while Angular will intercept the hash part and say 'perform an AJAX request to get the information about user 1'. So if I just change '#/1' to '#/2' I won't get a full reload of the page.

I'd also like a 'myapp.com/todo/#1' page with the same behaviour with the todo lists. If I come from the user page to this one I get a full reload (because they're completely different pages).

How should I configure the $location service to get this working ?
I've tried setting the HTML5 mode to true, but when I click a link, I never get a full reload, and the hash character is not in the URL.
I also tried setting HTML5 mode to false, and `hashPrefix('')` so I get the full reload when I change pages, but `$location.hash()` returns an empty string and `$location.path()` returns '/1'.

Bonus question: what if I also want to put the ID of an item of the todo list, something like 'myapp.com/todo/#1/#2' ? (having different hash parts or something) ?

Comment: *"because they're completely different pages"* ... use an angular router so they are all in same page. No need for page reload when using a router

Comment: that's one of the points I'm not sure about: is it mandatory to use a router when enabling HTML5 mode ? Because I don't want to at the moment

Comment: don't want to do what? if you aren't using a router and loading different pages then really not sure how your app works without some code provided and a better explanation of what you are trying to do

Comment: You really need either `ngRouter` or `ui.router`. HTML 5 mode is simply for prettier URLs.